# check message on xmlhttprequest issue

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest

I have this script that checks messages and is work fine, but in the script on function includejs is for opening a notification in bottom corner of the page that anounce user that a notification has arived, similar to facebook, but the problem is on the page, the notification box apears in multiple boxex and i want to show only one notification box per arived message. For notifications i use: Lobibox notify library!

This is the js script:

```
function checkMessage(){
    //This if check is required to take care of the browser compatibility problem
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) 
    {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
        xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    else
    {// code for IE6, IE5
        xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }

    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() //when the request is submitted...
    {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200) //...and everything is ok...
        {

            if(xmlhttp.responseText>0){

                function includeJs(jsFilePath) {
                    var js = document.createElement("script");

                    js.type = "text/javascript";
                    js.src = jsFilePath;

                    document.body.appendChild(js);
                }

                includeJs("notify/demo/demo.js");
                document.title="("+xmlhttp.responseText+") "+" Welcome to the page"; 
                document.getElementById('checkMsg').innerHTML="<b>" + xmlhttp.responseText+"</b>";

            } 

            if(xmlhttp.responseText > 1)

                document.getElementById('notes').innerHTML="<b> You have (" + xmlhttp.responseText+") new notifications!</b>";
            else

                document.getElementById('notes').innerHTML="<b> You have (" + xmlhttp.responseText+") Notification!</b>";
        } 

    }

    //and finally send the request to the php page 
    xmlhttp.open("GET","checkMessage.php?user_id="+"1",true); 
    xmlhttp.send();
}
```

On the page i have:

```
<div id="checkMsg"></div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="notifications.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            setInterval(checkMessage, 2000);
        </script>
<div id="notes"></div>
```

demo.js code:

```
 $('#notification').ready(function () {
                Lobibox.notify('success', {
                    delay: 15000,
                    size: 'mini',
                    title: 'Notification Box!',
                    msg: 'You have new messages in your box, check them!.'
                });
            });
```

Comment: I don't see anything in the code yiou posted that creates multiple alert boxes. Every time it runs it overwrites `notes` and `checkMsg` with the response text.

Comment: The notify script is ok, is working fine, is "demo.js" from includejs, but the problem is from here i guess, bcz of setinterval timer check, when two seconds has passed the notification box is poppin' up and never stops

Comment: You could save the response text in a global variable. When you get the new response text, check if it's different from the variable, and don't display a notification if it hasn't changed.

Comment: If you want to clarify your question, use the "edit" link. Don't put code in comments.

Comment: @Barmar can u help me with this?

Comment: I don't see how your code, as-is, could create multiple *boxes* like you're insisting. As @Barmar pointed out initially, `notes` and `checkMsg` would simply be overwritten on each cycle of your interval. Not appended to the last. Do you have additional code that you're leaving out?

Comment: So you're using the [notify()](https://notifyjs.com/) library? Would have been helpful to know that up-front.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a variable to remember the last message, and don't display a notification if it hasn't changed.

```
var lastResponse = null;
function checkMessage(){
    //This if check is required to take care of the browser compatibility problem
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) 
    {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
        xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    else
    {// code for IE6, IE5
        xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }

    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() //when the request is submitted...
    {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200) //...and everything is ok...
        {

            if(xmlhttp.responseText>0 && xmlhttp.responseText != lastResponse) {
                lastResponse = xmlhttp.responseText;

                function includeJs(jsFilePath) {
                    var js = document.createElement("script");

                    js.type = "text/javascript";
                    js.src = jsFilePath;

                    document.body.appendChild(js);
                }

                includeJs("notify/demo/demo.js");
                document.title="("+xmlhttp.responseText+") "+" Welcome to the page"; 
                document.getElementById('checkMsg').innerHTML="<b>" + xmlhttp.responseText+"</b>";

            } 

            if(xmlhttp.responseText > 1)

                document.getElementById('notes').innerHTML="<b> You have (" + xmlhttp.responseText+") new notifications!</b>";
            else

                document.getElementById('notes').innerHTML="<b> You have (" + xmlhttp.responseText+") Notification!</b>";
        } 

    }

    //and finally send the request to the php page 
    xmlhttp.open("GET","checkMessage.php?user_id="+"1",true); 
    xmlhttp.send();
}
```

Comment: Not working i get this error: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier - at, if(xmlhttp.responseText>0 and xmlhttp.responseText != lastResponse)

Comment: Oops, that should be `&&`.

Comment: done, is ok now, but the notifications is still poppin' up :))

Comment: I had another typo: `lastRespone` should be `lastResponse`

Comment: is ok now! Thanks bro!